# Vectors which are stretched the most in a linear transform(maximise vector norm)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Lets say we have a linear transform $A$ and we wish to find the direction in which $A$ stretches the space the most. So we let consider all $||=1$ and try to find this $x$. We wish to maximize || for vectors $||=1$

So it is $max (()⋅())=max (^^)$

And then my book concludes

> so it is the eigenvectors of $^$

How did it reach this conclusion? And why $^$? I thought that it would be obvious that in a transform the eigenvectors of that transform are the ones that are stretched the most as those are the principal directions in which the matrix acts. What does $A^TA$ have to do with $A$'s action? Whats the intution behind this?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that your book had covered eigensystems of quadratic forms somewhere before this point. You might also think about what the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ could be.

Answer (score 1):

Define 
$$
L(x, \lambda) = |Ax| - \lambda(|x| - 1) = (Ax)^T Ax  - \lambda(x^T x- 1)= x^T A^T A x - \lambda(x^T x- 1)
$$
For convenience, I'm going to rewrite this using the Einstein summation convention. We have
\begin{align}
L(x, \lambda) &= x_i (A^T A)_{ik} x_k -\lambda(x_i x_i - 1)
\\&= x_i(A^T_{ij} A_{jk}) x_k - \lambda(x_i x_i - 1)
\\&= x_i A_{ji} A_{jk} x_k - \lambda(x_i x_i - 1)
\end{align}
The partial derivatives of $L$ must vanish at every maximum of $|Ax|$ subject to the constraint $|x| - 1 = 0$ (i.e. $|x| = 1$). We compute
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_a} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_a} \left( x_i A_{ji} A_{jk} x_k - \lambda(x_i x_i - 1) \right)
\\&= \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_a} A_{ji} A_{jk} x_k + x_i A_{ji} A_{jk} \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_a} - \lambda\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_a} x_i + x_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_a}\right)
\\&= \delta_{ia} A_{ji} A_{jk} x_k + x_i A_{ji} A_{jk} \delta_{ka} - \lambda \left(\delta_{ia} x_i + x_i \delta_{ia} \right)
\\&= A_{ja} A_{jk} x_k + x_i A_{ji} A_{ja} - \lambda(x_a + x_a)
\\&= A^T_{aj} A_{jk} x_k + A_{aj}^T A_{ji} x_i - 2\lambda x_a
\\&= (A^T A)_{ak} x_k + (A^T A)_{ai} x_i - 2\lambda x_a
\\&= (A^T A ) x + (A^T A) x - 2\lambda x = 2(A^T A)x - 2\lambda x
\end{align} 
Rearranging we find
$$
2(A^T A) x = 2\lambda x
$$
So
$$
(A^T A)x = \lambda x
$$
Thus, if $x$ is a maximum of $|Ax|$ with $|x| = 1$, it must satisfy $(A^T A)x = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, if $x$ is a maximum of $|Ax|$ with $|x| = 1$, then $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T A$.

As a bonus, we find
$$
|Ax| = (Ax)^T (Ax) = x^T A^T A x = x^T ((A^T A) x) = x^T(\lambda x) = \lambda (x^T x) = \lambda |x| = \lambda
$$
That is, $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $|Ax|$. If $x$ does in fact maximize $|Ax|$, then $|Ax| = |A|_{op}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) for the definition of $|A|_{op}$).

We conclude that if $x$ maximizes $|Ax|$ with $|x| = 1$, then $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^T A$ with eigenvalue $|A|_{op}$.

Comment: Your answer while mathematically correct does not help me overcome my prior feeling hat eigenvalues of A should be the most stretched sectors.can you comment on some of the other questions I asked in the last part?

Comment: I don't have a lot to say in answer to the questions asked in the last part. Someone else might have more to say. Note that $|Av| = v^T (A^T A) v$, so $A^T A$ naturally enters into discussions about "stretching." A more elementary point is that $A$ doesn't necessarily have eigenvectors. For example, $A$ could be an $n \times m$ matrix with $n \neq m$, in which case the equation $Av = \lambda v$ doesn't even make sense.